# Material UI - How to stretch Grid container to parent height and width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

**Problem**

I cannot work how to get a `Grid` container element to stretch to the height and width of it's parent element without modifying the height and width using the `style` prop or editing the style with the `makeStyles/useStyles` hook.

I am sure there has to be a simpler way. I have created a sandbox with what I would like (written with vanilla React) and what I have so far (written with Material UI components).

The reason I am not just using regular `Box` components is due to of the lack responsive controls it has in comparison to `Grid`.

**Example**

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-shadow-x90gf?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was overcomplicating things and under appreciating the power of `Box`.

`Box` is responsive. My takeaway is to use `Grid` sparingly on items that have heights and widths and use `Box` in combination with the `Hidden` for screen layouts.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Box bgcolor="green" display="flex" height="100vh" width="100vw">
      <Box bgcolor="red" flex={{ xs: 1, sm: 2 }} />
      <Box
        bgcolor="yellow"
        display="flex"
        flex={1}
        flexDirection={{ xs: "column", sm: "row" }}
      >
        <Box bgcolor="blue" flex={{ xs: 1, sm: 6 }} />
        <Box bgcolor="purple" flex={{ xs: 11, sm: 6 }} />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```